# For loop in tensorflow/ keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a for loop within a model definition (and attempting to recreate TabNet in keras).

```py
class TabNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, steps, n_d, n_a, gamma=1.3):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_d, self.n_a, self.steps = n_d, n_a, steps
        self.shared = SharedBlock(n_d+n_a)
        self.first_block = SharedBlock(n_a)
        self.decision_blocks = [DecisionBlock(n_d+n_a)] * steps
        self.prior_scale = Prior(input_dim, gamma)
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.attention = [AttentiveTransformer(input_dim)] * steps
        self.final = layers.Dense(output_dim)
        self.eps = 1e-8

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x):
        self.prior_scale.reset()
        final_out = 0
        M_loss = 0

        x = self.bn(x)
        attention = self.first_block(self.shared(x))
        for i in range(self.steps):
            mask = self.attention[i](attention, self.prior_scale.P)
            M_loss += tf.reduce_sum(mask * tf.math.log(mask + self.eps), axis=-1) / self.steps

            prior = self.prior_scale(mask)
            out = self.decision_blocks[i](self.shared(x * prior))
            attention, output = out[:,:self.n_a], out[:,self.n_a:]
            final_out += tf.nn.relu(output)

        return self.final(final_out), M_loss
```

If you're unaware of what those individual blocks are, simply assume that they are linear layers. I have [a colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_ZwsKl3aCxGEvxsdpxN3KI7hIfFRSMfP?usp=sharing) with the full code if you wish to see what they actually are.

However, I cannot train it as I am getting the error `iterating over` tf.Tensor `is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.`. I have decorated it, and still does not help.

I am fairly certain it is the for loop that is causing me the error when I do `model.fit(train_x, train_y)`. Would appreciate any thoughts on how to implement the above for loop in the tensorflow way. `tf.while_loop` is all I have seen so far and the examples given are fairly simplistic compared to what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my proposal...

I don't know what your network exactly do but what I can see is that you want to produce 2 outputs and combine them inside your loss. One of your output is also the results of some hidden operation inside the network (M_loss).

so if you want to return 2 outputs, 2 targets are needed in keras in order to make a fit. In the code I provide below, the first target is the real labels and the other is a fake output (an array of zeros).

As said before, you try to build a combined loss as `sparse_entropy(y_true, y_pred) - reg_sparse * M_loss`. To make this possible **I split the loss in two pieces (one for each output): the sparse part and the M_loss part**. The sparse loss is simply SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) from keras, while for the M_loss, I wrote this function following your code

```
def m_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  m = tf.reduce_mean(y_pred, keepdims=True)
  return m
```

the `m_loss` use only 'y_pred' that are the hidden pieces of your network. the y_true in this case doesn't matter for the required operation. this is why we pass an array of zeros when fitting.

At this point, we have to combine the two losses and this possible in keras in this way

```
reg_sparse = 0.1

model.compile('Adam', loss=[sce, m_loss], loss_weights=[1,-reg_sparse])
model.fit(train_x, [train_y, np.zeros(train_y.shape[0])], epochs=3)
```

in this case, the final loss is the result of the combination of `1*sce + (-reg_sparse)*m_loss`

this is the full running code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/152q1rmqTJ0dWLbFN8PqzCBhWkVKirkU5?usp=sharing

I also make some little changes in TabNet, for example in the way final_out and M_loss are created

Answer (score 1):

No actually it is not a problem of `for` loop. I checked your code, the problem was that you **forgot to call the superclass constructor in your** `SharedBlock`, `DecisionBlock` and `Prior`.

For e.g your code should look like.

```
class SharedBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, mult=tf.sqrt(0.5)):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = FCBlock(units)
        self.layer2 = FCBlock(units)
        self.mult = mult
```

After doing these changes you will not see that error again but something else comes up.

```
TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1147 predict_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    <ipython-input-46-f609cb1acdfa>:15 call  *
        self.prior_scale.reset()

    TypeError: tf__reset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'len_x'
```

To resolve this issue you will need to do following changes in the class `class Prior(layers.Layer):`.

```
def reset(self, len_x=1.0):
        self.P = 1.0
```

Then you will get another issue.

AttributeError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1147 predict_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
<ipython-input-46-f609cb1acdfa>:26 call  *
    out = self.decision[i](self.shared(x * prior))

AttributeError: 'TabNet' object has no attribute 'decision'
```

For this issue I will request to open another question as I think you main issue is resolved.

**UPDATE:**

You can look into the comment section of this answer, there a solution has been provided for the issue `AttributeError: 'TabNet' object has no attribute 'decision'`

**UPDATE: 21/07**

I have to disappoint you again that the issue is not with the `for` loop.

If you look closely at the error log you will see that the issue is due to the `full_loss` function.

```
<ipython-input-10-07e59f23d230>:7 full_loss  *
        logits, M_loss = y_pred
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:561 __iter__
        self._disallow_iteration()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:554 _disallow_iteration
        self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:532 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

The exact problem is caused by the below statement.

```
logits, M_loss = y_pred
```

If you use the below code that does not use your loss function you will see a different result.

```
model.compile('Adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=1)

Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 1
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy_1/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at <ipython-input-26-d39f533b7a69>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_18003]
```

I do not understand the model code completely and the `model.summary()` is not that helpful in your case. There is some problem with your last layer, at least the error message suggests that you do not have ample neurons (1 for each class).

I will suggest looking into the last layer and the loss function.

Why I am sure it is not due to `for` loop is for the fact that even if you comment the `for` loop you will still receive the same error.

I hope I have helped you further, took me a few hours to figure it out.

Comment: it's self.decision_blocks and not self.decision. the same errors raise with n_a and n_d, it can be solved calling them with self.n_a and self.n_d. after fixing this it works without a problem

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to look through my code (and especially my bugs). Truly appreciate it!

Comment: I have fixed the bugs that you have mentioned. Now the error is back to being about the for loop. If you have any ideas on how to fix that, would love to hear it.